# create PDO class

Tags: php, pdo

How do I `create a class` to connect to a database with **PDO**?

So that in `__construct` I can `save the connection in a variable` and use it in any method I want.

**Note: I did this myself, but in any method, when I call the variable that handles the connection, I encounter null.**

Is such a thing possible? please guide me.

Comment: [here](https://gist.github.com/jonahlyn/1186647) a example

Comment: @SimoneRossaini fyi, that's a very bad example, vulnerable to SQL injections and full of cargo cult code.

Comment: Can you explaine where is vulnerable?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini any use of this class is vulnerable. for example `$rows = $database->getQuery("SELECT * FROM table where id=$id"); ` I can make a full review if you post it on codereview site

Comment: @SimoneRossaini not to mention that a wrapper for PDO is in itself a questionable design. You inevitably end up debugging the wrapper instead of your 'for pay' code. .02

Comment: My bad sorry!!!